# GitHub for Windows Install Error

Tags: windows-7, installation, git, github

I'm trying to install the GitHub for Windows that I downloaded from the GitHub site. However, I get the following error message:

> Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.

I'm curious if anyone else has ran into this issue, and knows of a fix?

Below is the info from the log file:

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO     Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)  Common
>   Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.17929   System.Deployment.dll       :
>   4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL  clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL  dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by:
>   FX45RTMREL    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          :
>   github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
>
> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
>   http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in
>   exception. Following failure messages were detected:      + The system
>   cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     * [10/4/2012 12:22:45 PM] : Activation of
>   http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [10/4/2012 12:22:45 PM] System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>         - The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32
>   Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)             at
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType
>   storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String
>   deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

It seems like the error message itself isn't specific to Git, but more of a universal message that Windows installer throws because I noticed when doing a Google search people trying to install other applications had an identical error message.

I wasn't able to find any information on GitHub's website about this error either. :(

Thanks for any help-

Comment: It looks like maybe you need to install .NET 4.5, or possibly reinstall .NET 4.5? Are you able to run other .NET programs?

Comment: I've installed .NET 4.5, but I'm still not having any luck with the GitHub application. I can run other .NET programs.

Comment: Darn, too easy I suppose. Just even clicking your link in that log file (http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application) was enough to launch GitHUB for me, which I already had installed. If you click that link, does it even try to do something?

Comment: I've tried running that too, but I get the same error. I believe the error is actually "Click Once" app related, and not GitHub itself. So far, GitHub support hasn't been able to help me with this issue either.

Comment: That's actually good news - now you can try a bunch of fixes specific to that: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/57f09a43-8354-42fe-9e74-af6eb157a5b5

Comment: Adding the possible solution as an 'answer' just in case it helps.

Answer (score 16):

- From the Windows Start Menu, choose "Run"
  (or type <kbd>[image: Windows] (Windows Key)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
- Enter the following, depending on your version of Windows, then click the "OK" button:

  - On Windows XP:

    ```
    %userprofile%\Local Settings\Apps
    ```

    (which may be `C:\Documents & Settings\(your username)\Local Settings\Apps`)
  - On Windows VISTA / 7:

    ```
    %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps
    ```

    or

    ```
    %LocalAppData%\Apps
    ```

    (e.g., `C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Local\Apps`)
- Delete the 2.0 folder

Comment: Set to community wiki because I copy/pasted this from somewhere else.

Comment: I tried this with no luck a few days ago.

Comment: Well it was worth a shot, sorry. :( I'd still pursue solving ClickOnce applications not starting in general, that does seem to be the actual problem.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Having a similar problem with the same message on Windows 8.

Comment: It tried it, but does not work for me. It still shows the error : Unable to retrieve application files. Files corrupt in deployment.

Comment: No longer works. Tried with the new GitHub Desktop :/