# Windows Github install error: System.Net.WebException

Tags: windows-7, git, github

While installing, I got this error (from the log file).  I tried the solutions to this similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/483515/github-for-windows-install-error)

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [5/7/2013 8:19:29 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_41_2/Images/App.ico.deploy did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install?  The error message is pretty clear the file isn't located where the installer thinks its located contact the author of the product.  Although I just verified that the .ico file is located at that location.  So it sounds like this is a networking issue on your end.

Comment: Sorry thought the title showed it.  I'm trying to install github windows.  How would i fix the networking error?

Comment: @TOM - Can you ping **http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com**?

Comment: nope, it timed out. why would this be?

Comment: Your network is blocking the connection.  You will have to  investigate.